# Why the div with class name "topnav" is not being displayed in palegreen color?

Tags: html, css, css-float

```css
.topnav{
 background-color: palegreen;
}
.topnav a{
 float: left;
 }
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
        <a href="">Home</a>
        <a href="">News</a>
        <a href="">Contact</a>
        <a href="">About</a>
 </div>
```

> Using above code I am trying to create a navbar but I am not able to give background colour to the topnav div?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you tried and your one challenge that code presents you with. Posting pictures of code is NOT code and not really allowed for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have floated child element, the parent div height gets collapsed.
to avoid this you need to clear floats, so that parent can gain height

```
.topnav::after{
 content:"";
 clear:both;
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<style>
.topnav{
background-color:palegreen;
}
.topnav a{
float:left;
}

.topnav::after{
content:"";
clear:both;
display:block;
}
</style>

<div class="topnav">
<a href="">home</a>
<a href="">home</a><a href="">home</a><a href="">home</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering it.
Can you please some resource from where I can learn about this concept!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp